# Order of messages affecting properties apart from 'retries' in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We know already **max.in.flight.requests.per.connection  to 1** will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first.  Because of this property may affect the order of the message in Kafka . 
   Now question here is apart from this retires property settings, any other property will affect the order of message?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of delivery is critical for you. If you are looking for an ordered delivery of your messages, you have following two options.

```
Use synchronous send.
use asynchronous send and set max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Response Rohit. My questions here is apart from this property (max.in.flight.requests.per.connection) any other property will affect the order of message or not ?

Comment: no,there is no other property which affects the ordering of messages